# Removing or replacing a stylesheet (a <link>) with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I do this?

I tried

```js
$('link[title="mystyle"]').remove();
```

and although the element is removed, the styles are still applied to the current page (in both Opera and Firefox).

Is there any other way?

Comment: stuff like `$('link[title="mystyle"]').remove()` works now, it was an issue with old browsers (when this question was asked years ago)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To cater for ie you have to set the stylesheet to be disabled as it keeps the css styles in memory so removing the element will not work, it can also cause it to crash in some instances if I remember correctly.

This also works for cross browser.

e.g

```
document.styleSheets[0].disabled = true;
```

//so in your case using jquery try

```
$('link[title=mystyle]')[0].disabled=true;
```

Comment: Nice redsquare, I didn't know about this. Welcome back, btw.

Comment: @karim79, thanks, been busy and got bored. Got the bug back now!

Comment: These days, the "jQuery way" would look like `$('link[title=mystyle]').prop('disabled',true);`

Comment: This is no longer true; now in the future (7 years later) removing link tag is enough

Comment: `$('link[title=mystyle]')[0].disabled=true;` didn't wok for me, but `$('link[id=mystyle]')[0].disabled=true;` worked. I had to use the id instead of title.

Answer (score 20):

I managed to do it with:

```
$('link[title="mystyle"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

it seems this is the only way to remove the styles from memory.
then I added:

```
$('link[title="mystyle"]').remove();
```

to remove the element too.

Answer (score 11):

To disable your selected stylesheet:

```js
$('link[title="mystyle"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

If you never want that stylesheet to be applied again, you can then [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) it. But don’t do that if you want to be able to re-enable it later.

To re-enable the stylesheet, do this (as long as you didn’t `remove` the stylesheet’s element):

```js
$('link[title="mystyle"]').prop('disabled', false);
```

In the code above, it is important to use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), not [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). If you use `.attr`, the code will work in some browsers, but not Firefox. This is because, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-disabled), `disabled` is a [property of the `HTMLLinkElement` DOM object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLinkElement#Properties), but *not* an attribute of the `link` HTML element. Using `disabled` as an HTML attribute is nonstandard.

Answer (score 8):

no jQuery solution

if you can add id to your link tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css" id="styles-animations">

document.getElementById("styles-animations").disabled = true;
```

if you know index position of your css file in document

```
document.styleSheets[0].disabled = true; // first
document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1].disabled = true; // last
```

if you want to disable style by name you can use this function

```
/**
 * @param [string]  [styleName] [filename with suffix e.g. "style.css"]
 * @param [boolean] [disabled]  [true disables style]
 */
var disableStyle = function(styleName, disabled) {
    var styles = document.styleSheets;
    var href = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
        href = styles[i].href.split("/");
        href = href[href.length - 1];

        if (href === styleName) {
            styles[i].disabled = disabled;
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

note: make sure style file name is unique so you don't have "dir1/style.css" and "dir2/style.css". In that case it would disable only first style.

Answer (score 5):

Using pure javascript:

```
var stylesheet = document.getElementById('stylesheetID');
stylesheet.parentNode.removeChild(stylesheet);
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove a stylesheet:

```
$('link[src="<path>"]').remove();
```

To Replace a stylesheet:

```
$('link[src="<path>"]').attr('src','<NEW_FILE_PATH>');
```

Comment: to make it work in 2022 I had to replace `src` with `href` like so:

`$('link[href="https://example.com/styleshett.css"]').attr('href', 'my-stylesheet.css');`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it only with the href attribute:

```
$('link[href="https://example.com/mycss.css"]').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 solution:

```
const disableStyle = styleName => {
  const styles = document.styleSheets;
  let href = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
    if (!styles[i].href) {
      continue;
    }
    href = styles[i].href.split("/");
    href = href[href.length - 1];
    if (href === styleName) {
      styles[i].disabled = true;
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

Use it like `disableStyle("MyUnwantedFile.css");`.

Comment: Thanks for proving an ES6 solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's both an add & remove using the disabling principle mentioned in a number of these other posts to prevent cross browser issues.  Note how my add checks to see if the sheet already exists, in which case it just enables it.  Also, in contrast to some answers, this is designed to work using the url to a .css file as the sole argument to the functions (insulating the client from the use of `id` or `title` attributes).

```
function element( id ){ return document.getElementById( id ); }

function addStyleSheet( url ){
    var id = _styleSheetUrlToId( url );
    if( !_enableStyleSheet( id ) ) {
        var link  = document.createElement("link");
        link.href = url;
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.rel  = "stylesheet"; 
        link.id   = id; 
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( link );
    }
}

function removeStyleSheet( url )
{ _enableStyleSheet( _styleSheetUrlToId( url ), false ); }

// "protected" function
function _styleSheetUrlToId( url ){ 
    var urlParts = url.split("/");
    return urlParts[urlParts.length-1].split(".")[0]
           + "-style";
}

// "protected" function
// returns if the sheet was found 
function _enableStyleSheet( id, enable ) {
    if( typeof(enable) == "undefined" ) enable = true;
    var sheet = element( id );
    if( sheet ) {
        sheet.disabled = !enable;
        return true;        
    }
    return false;
}
```