# How to dynamically remove a stylesheet from the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet

Is there a way to dynamically remove the current stylesheet from the page?

For example, if a page contains:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://..." />
```

...is there a way to later disable it with JavaScript? Extra points for using jQuery.

Comment: Duplicate of [Removing or replacing a stylesheet (a <link>) with JavaScript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3182840/578288). See also [jQuery – enable/disable all style sheets on page on click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15824089/578288).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing or replacing a stylesheet (a <link>) with JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182840/removing-or-replacing-a-stylesheet-a-link-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Well, assuming you can target it with jQuery it should be just as simple as calling `remove()` on the element:

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet]').remove();
```

That will remove *all* external stylesheets on the page. If you know part of the url then you can remove just the one you're looking for:

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="foo.com"]').remove();
```

And in Javascript

this is an example of remove all with query selector and foreach array

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('link[rel=stylesheet]'), function(element){
      try{
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
      }catch(err){}
    });

//or this is similar
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel=stylesheet]');
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
}
```

Comment: *[facepalm]* I totally forgot about the attribute selector.

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3182840/578288), just removing the `link` element is not enough. You should make it [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLinkElement#Properties) first, with [`.prop('disabled', true)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). Though it’s possible that browsers have changed since that question was written (2010), and you don’t need to disable the `link`.

Comment: FWIW Rory, I just opened the DevTools panel in Chrome and selected the stylesheet link for this page and pressed delete and all the styling went away. I suppose it's possible Chrome is doing something special-casey but I doubt it.

Comment: `.remove()` doesnt seem to affect the page, see http://binternet.co.il/contact-form/ and click on `rtl` button twice, its stuck on RTL...any idea why?

Comment: Dude, you made my day!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: $('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="stylesheet-link"]').remove(); works fine but is there a way to remove stylesheet irrespective of the version's in it? Like style.css?ver=1.0.1 and the version will be changing

Comment: @rahulpatel just do a string check on the href attribute when looping over the elements

Comment: After removing, will the rules continue to affect the page?

Answer (score 28):

If you know the ID of the stylesheet, use the following.  Any other method of getting the stylesheet works as well, of course.  This is straight DOM and doesn't require using any libraries.

```
var sheet = document.getElementById(styleSheetId);
sheet.disabled = true;
sheet.parentNode.removeChild(sheet);
```

Comment: After removing, will the rules continue to affect the page?

Answer (score 11):

I found this page whilst looking for a way to remove style sheets using jquery. I thought I'd found the right answer when I read the following

> If you know part of the url then you can remove just the one you're looking for:
>   `$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="foo.com"]').remove();"`

I liked this solution because the style sheets I wanted to remove had the same name but were in different folders. However this code did not work so I changed the operator to `*=` and it works perfectly:

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href*="mystyle"]').remove();
```

Just thought I'd share this in case it's useful for someone.

Comment: I found the accepted answer did not work for me, using * instead of ~ did the trick . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940706/tilde-in-jquery-selector

Answer (score 9):

This will disable any [stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) matching the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) `searchRegEx` provided against the URL of each stylesheet.

```
let searchRegEx = /example.*/;

for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    if (document.styleSheets[i].href.search(searchRegEx) != -1) {
        document.styleSheets[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Nobody has mentioned removing a specific stylesheet without an ID in plain Javascript:

```
 document.querySelector('link[href$="something.css"]').remove()
```

("$=" to find at end of href)

Answer (score 4):

This will reset your page's styling, removing all of the style-elements. Also, jQuery isn't required.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('style,[rel="stylesheet"],[type="text/css"]'), function(element){
  try{
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
  }catch(err){}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for disable all `<style>` from html

```
// this disable all style of the website...
var cant = document.styleSheets.length
for(var i=0;i<cant;i++){
    document.styleSheets[i].disabled=true;
}

//this is the same disable all stylesheets
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.styleSheets, function(element){
  try{
    element.disabled = true;
  }catch(err){}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Damien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35930790/11302317), the `test` method (which returns `true` or `false`) would probably be a better fit than `search` and is slightly faster. Using this method would yield:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    if (/searchRegex/.test(document.styleSheets[i].href)) {
        document.styleSheets[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

If you don't care about IE support this can be cleaned up with a for...of loop

```
for (const styleSheet of document.styleSheets) {
    if (/searchRegex/.test(styleSheet)) {
        styleSheet.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Suppose you want to remove a class myCssClass then the most easy way to do it is element.classList.remove("myCssClass");