# Tilde in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

My understanding of the tilde's function in Javascript is that it performs a bitwise not operation (i.e. 1 becomes 0 and vice versa; 1000 becomes 0111). However, I've recently begun work on an existing project where my predecessor has included a lot of code like this:

```
var iValuation = $('div[class~="iValuation"]');
```

Can anyone tell me what the purpose of the tilde in this instance is? I've not come across it before and haven't been able to find any reference to it online.

Comment: Browsing http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ leads one to [this](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)

Comment: That's not a JavaScript operator, it's a jQuery selector. The API has [an entire page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't a JavaScript operator. It appears in a string.

Since that string is passed to the jQuery function, and it doesn't look like a piece of HTML, it is a [selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Specifically one of the [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors):

> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "val". If "val" contains whitespace, it will never represent anything (since the words are separated by spaces). Also if "val" is the empty string, it will never represent anything.

Answer (score 11):

Tiled used as selector means

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   containing a given word, delimited by spaces.

which is not a JavaScript operator at all.

More from doc:

> This selector matches the test string against each word in the
>   attribute value, where a "word" is defined as a string delimited by
>   whitespace. The selector matches if the test string is exactly equal
>   to any of the words.

For example:

```
<input name="man-news" />
<input name="milk man" />
<input name="letterman2" />
<input name="newmilk" />
```

`$('input[name~="man"]')` will select only second `input`, because its attribute `name` is separated by `space`.

For detail see ***[here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)***

Comment: Worth noting that that's purely JQUERY functionality, not anything innate to Javascript.  The OP's understand of what the tilde does is correct insofar as stock JS goes.

Answer (score 3):

`$` is the `jQuery` selector function, which contains a `CSS3` Selector String: According to the [`CSS3` Selector Definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/), the selector you encountered selects:

> E[foo~="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to "bar"

in the `DOM`. Because the Tilde is wrapped in a string, it is not working as an operator.

Answer (score 3):

In case you're wondering about the **difference** between

```
[class~="foo"]
```

and

```
[class*="foo"]
```

**`~`** will match only **with whitespace** around (e.g. 'foo bar' but not 'foo-1')
**`*`** will match **with or without whitespace** around (e.g. 'foo bar' and 'foo-1')

`~` - Attribute Spaced Selector
`*` - Attribute Contains Selector