# Can you change css class precedence at loadtime?

Tags: css, class, operator-precedence, tabletools

I'm working with jQuery datatables and oTableTools aButtons. I'm doing this:

```
oTableTools: {
    aButtons: [
        {
            sExtends: 'text',
            sButtonText: 'Add +',
            fnClick: function ( nButton, oConfig, oFlash ) {/*stuff*/},
            sButtonClass: 'btn-success'
        }
    ]
},
```

My problem is that the `a.DTTT_button` class on dataTable.tableTools.css:38 is overriding the `.btn-success` class on bootstrap-combined.min.css:9, so my button is grey instead of green. They are both being loaded from external sources, so I can't edit them, and changing the order in which they are loaded did not affect anything, presumably because the defintion in dataTable.tableTools.css is more specific, what with being specifically for anchors.

Is there a way to force `sButtonClass` to take precedence over `a.DTTT_button` at loadtime, or am I going to have to create a new class in my local css file to duplicate the style I want and call it instead? That feels less clean to me, so I'd rather not do it if I don't absolutely have to.

Comment: If you want to "force precedence" in the way to described, you can use **!important**... however this is generally considered **bad practice**. More details (and better solutions) here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3706876/1538708

Comment: I can't add !important because the css files are loaded from external sources; I can't change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cleanest way given the parameters in this case is actually to create a `a.sButtonClass` selector in your "local css file" that loads after the `a.DTTT_button` class. Specificity will match, but the cascade will win for `a.sButtonClass`. I know you said this "feels less clean," but your contraints of not being able to manipulate the two css files make it one of the cleanest solutions. Also, if you are using a preprocessor (like [LESS](http://www.lesscss.org/) that boostrap is based off of), then you can have your local enhancement automatically match the bootstrap class by using that class as a mixin for your more specific selector.

***However, an alternative*** is to not apply those styles by a class at all, and write the `sButtonClass` styles directly to the `style` attribute of the anchor element, as that will override anything that `a.DTTT_button` is doing (assuming `a.DTTT_button` does not have `!important` tags on its properties).

Answer (score 0):

You can't change precidence unless you want to remove and re-insert the sytesheets into the DOM using JavaScript in the order you want. That's a little ugly, but it can be done.

The proper way is to use [CSS specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), but since you can't edit the external files, manipulating the DOM may be the only way to go.

This may help:

Add: [Add stylesheet to Head using javascript in body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833759/add-stylesheet-to-head-using-javascript-in-body)

Remove: [How to dynamically remove a stylesheet from the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033650/how-to-dynamically-remove-a-stylesheet-from-the-current-page)