# jQuery – enable/disable all style sheets on page on click

Tags: jquery, css, stylesheet

Is it possible to detect all style sheets on the current page with a click of a ‘disable/enable CSS’ button and disable them on the first click so none of the styling applies, and then restore them once again on second click? Any idea what the jQuery would look like, if it’s possible?

Comment: Is there a practical application here?

Comment: @user113215 just want to know if it was possible:)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

this should disable all of them, then the opposite to renable them:

```
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: Short and sweet. Works great. Thanks MaxOvrdrv!

Comment: @mdmullinax your fiddle doesn't seem to work on button click!

Comment: @mdmullinax you're right works in chrome. Not in FF. Either way great answer! Upvoting your fiddle too :)

Comment: This does not work in Firefox. [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-disabled) that using `disabled` as an *HTML attribute* is **non-standard**; `disabled` is only a *DOM property*. You can fix your code by using `.prop('disabled', true)` and `.prop('disabled', false)` instead.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane is correct. Better to follow his suggestion.

Comment: Definitively see @RoryO'Kane answer below for a much more compatible solution on various browsers http://stackoverflow.com/a/18922945/954777

Answer (score 8):

To disable all stylesheets:

```js
$('link[rel~="stylesheet"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

To re-enable all stylesheets:

```js
$('link[rel~="stylesheet"]').prop('disabled', false);
```

I use [the `~=` attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation) here instead of `=` so that the selector will still work with stylesheets where the `rel` attribute is [`alternate stylesheet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets), not just `stylesheet`.

Also, it is important to use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), not [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). If you use `.attr`, the code will not work in Firefox. This is because, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-disabled), `disabled` is a [property of the `HTMLLinkElement` DOM object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLinkElement#Properties), but *not* an attribute of the `link` HTML element. Using `disabled` as an HTML attribute is nonstandard.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="somelink.com"]').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough example that relies on assigning an id to a style and then removing and restoring it using a variable.

**HTML**

```
<style id="test">
.test{
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
<div class="test">Something</div>
<div id="remove">Click to Remove</div>
<div id="restore">Click to Restore</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var css = $("#test");
$("#remove").click(function(){
    css.remove();
});

$("#restore").click(function(){
    $("head").append(css);
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/Fwhak/

Answer (score 0):

I found the found the following worked in all browsers for me:

```
CSS Link:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://basehold.it/22" data-role="baseline">

JQuery:
$('link[data-role="baseline"]').attr('href', '');
```

The above will disable only that one stylesheet, and this could be toggled on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method that you can try to do that thing.

```
$('*[rel=stylesheet]').attr('disabled', 'true');
$('link[rel=stylesheet]').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

and in other hand you remove that attribute

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet]').attr('disabled', 'false');
$('*[rel=stylesheet]').attr('disabled', 'false');
```