# Load and unload external stylesheets dynamically in AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stylesheet, dynamic-loading

I have two routes/views in my AngularJS application that are using conflicting CSS. I have two separate external stylesheets that I want to use for these routes. For example `foo.css` for `foo` route and `bar.css` for `bar` route. That way I can resolve the conflict.

However, I will have to load `bar.css` and unload `foo.css` when navigating from `foo` to `bar`.

How do I do this? Is there a library/module that can help me to achieve this scenario?

I've looked into `ocLazyLoad`, but I'm not sure how to unload the loaded CSS.

Answer (score 3):

### AngularJS Way

In a comment below, the OP suggested the way that seems most appropriate to me in AngularJS - using the `ng-disabled` directive. You just have to make `<html>` your `ng-app` attribute element so that the directive gets properly executed.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/style-1.css" ng-disabled="theme.name === 'theme1'">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/style-2.css" ng-disabled="theme.name === 'theme2'">
```

This way both styles get loaded immediately (causing no flicker on change later). Different approach would be needed if some of the styles should *not* be loaded initially.

### Original Answer

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824089/jquery-enable-disable-all-style-sheets-on-page-on-click). Then just find the appropriate `<link>` tags and enable/disable them at will. I don't think this has anything to do with AngularJS.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! However, I can add `ngDisabled` or `ngIf` directive to `<link>` elements, as you suggested, but that way I will not be able to delay view rendering and document will probably look unstyled for some time. I just don't want to [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) things up.

Comment: If you trigger disabling using the same variable on the same scope, both `<link>`s will get updated during the same `$digest` (both files will have been loaded on page load). So I wouldn't worry about flicker, the only possible issue is that both of your stylesheets will get applied until the first `$digest` sorts it out.

Comment: Well, I don't want them to be loaded optimistically. Not every user of the application will ever use the second route.

Comment: In that case, [there's already a question on SO dealing with the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695156/angular-js-load-css-and-js-files-dynamically).

Comment: Yeah, thanks )
I saw that question, but it's more generic than mine.
I'm probably looking for existing solution that can make it work.