# How to disable CSS on a specific page?

Tags: html, css

I am using 3 stylesheets (`style1`, `style2`, `style3`) for many pages.

- `style1` for my web header,
- `style2` for my contents and
- `style3` for footer

Now I want to apply a new `stylesheet` on my home page and disable `style2` for only home page.

I added new classes for different elements but at some places it is still detecting my previous `stylesheet`s. How can I disable CSS on a specific page?

Comment: We need to see the code you are having problems with.

Comment: here is web http://www.design.earnandearn.com/ , and i want to disable core.css for home page only

Comment: From your website it seemed that it was a simple `link` element. If so, simply remove the link element and replace it with the new stylesheet.

Comment: if i remove link all other pages will disturb :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15824131/2151050

Comment: Are you using `PHP` to echo those style links?

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not include the code to see how you doing it, and considering you are having the header as an include file:

USE PHP:

In your Home page before including header:

```
<?php $homepage = 1; ?>

//include your header//
```

In your header where you are referencing CSS:

```
<link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="css/style3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="<?php if($homepage == 1){ echo "css/Home-style.css";}else{ echo "css/style2.css";}?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Your files should be in PHP for this to work. 
change "Home-style.css" to your new CSS file for home page.

Answer (score 1):

Check for page then grab the dom stylesheets array object and disable anything you want .

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("<name in page url >") > -1) {

//Next line will disable the 2nd stylsheet in the document . 

 document.styleSheets[1].disabled = true;

}
```

Also fyi you can view all style sheets in the dom with:

```
console.log(document.styleSheets)
```

This should give you the appropriate index of whatever stylesheet you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `jQuery` to disable a `stylesheet` like :

```
<script>
$(function () {
  if (location.pathname.indexOf('/pagename') >= 0) {
    $('link[href*="/media/css/csspagename.css"]').prop('disable', true);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have already tries it by pasting it on my home page but not disbabled my required sheet
<script>
$(function () {
  if (location.pathname.indexOf('/') >= 0) {
    $('link[href*="../media/css/core.css"]').prop('disable', true);
  }
});
</script>