# Removing imported CSS on component end

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have many components that import hosted css files as follows:

```
<style scoped>
  @import 'https://test.com/path/to/my-stylesheets/styles.css';
</style>
```

What I am wanting is a way to remove these imported stylesheets on an end lifecycle hook such as `beforeDestroy`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do depends on `vue-loader` (if you're using webpack) and it looks like a counter intuitive. So, there's no reason for styles to be removed from document. What you can do is to define your CSS classes in stylesheets or as a data variable in viewmodel and assign/remove those classes during Vue component's lifecycle like beforeCreate/beforeDestroy etc. if you like.

Comment: Yeah I realise it seems counter intuitive. We are working with some legacy system integrations and long story short we need these sheets removed completely on destroy.

Comment: Well! I don't like to say this, you'll need to go super ugly. You'll need something like the link shared on `beforeDestroy` I think. But this pattern shouldn't be followed. Though it's just an idea

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033650/how-to-dynamically-remove-a-stylesheet-from-the-current-page