# how to remove css rel by javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a line on the top of the page,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
```

How do I remove it by jQuery or javascript?

Tired this way,but not working

```
$(link['style/style.css']).remove();
```

Comment: Why do you want to delete your stylesheet? That's like removing a tire from your car _while you're driving it_. Sure you can do it, but it isn't particularly smart.

Comment: Thanks :-) yes, I know, I'd like to remove it by js. if it is possible ?

Comment: `$("link[href='style/style.css']").remove()`

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3182851/642196).

Comment: removing the stylesheet won't unload the styles.

Comment: thanks for the answer, if i'like to remove names match style no matter what folder it is in, so the code would be like `$('link[href="*/style.css"]').remove();`?

Comment: @olo [`$('link[href$="/style.css"]')`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Comment: Are you trying to clear styles on the site or simply remove the dom element?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery selection by attribute is in this format:

```
$('link[href="style/style.css"]');
```

Then you need to disable it:

```
// prop() suggestion from @jahroy
$('link[href="style/style.css"]').prop("disabled", true);
```

[The docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: Slow down the downvote train. This is the correct way to do it. Selection by attribute is in the format I have given. Check the docs.

Comment: Shouldn't you use [jQuery.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) [in stead of _attr()_] to disable the link?  By the way, I did **not** downvote.  From the docs: "_The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting value._"

Comment: @jahroy, that would be better, huh? I fixed it. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: why don't remove it by $('link[href="style/style.css"]').remove()?

Comment: @Stiger, apparently it doesn't work that way from what I have read. `remove()` takes away the element but that stylesheet information is still there.

Answer (score 2):

In most modern browsers you can iterate through the list of stylesheets and disable the ones you want:

```
var toRemove = 'style/style.css';

[].forEach.call(document.styleSheets, function(styleSheet) {
    if (styleSheet.href && styleSheet.href.substr(-toRemove.length) === toRemove) {
        styleSheet.disabled = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but it may be a better way to achieve what you are trying to do:

If you are controlling the stylesheet and you want an easy way to turn it on and off then you may consider using the same trick that is used by [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). Instead of having in your stylesheet:

```
.some-class { color: red }
```

and then removing the entire stylesheet it in some cases, you can have:

```
.style-x .some-class { color: red }
```

and then in your HTML or JavaScript you can add "style-x" class to the **body** tag:

```
<body class="style-x">
  [...]
  <div class="some-class">red text</div>
  [...]
</body>
```

Removing the style in JavaScript is just removing the class style-x from the body tag, using `.className` in plain JavaScript or `.removeClass()` in jQuery.

That way you can have many "styles" in one concatenated and minified CSS file that can be activated and deactivated independently.

Answer (score 0):

This javascript snippet works

[how to remove css rel by javascript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704093/how-to-remove-css-rel-by-javascript-or-jquery?noredirect=1#comment24044990_16704093)

```
document.styleSheets[0].disabled = true;
```

Comment: That will disable the first, not necessarily the one you want.