# How to unload a css file using only its filename?

Tags: javascript

I have a css file in my `<head>` tag, defined as follows:

```
<link href="foo/bar/baz.css" rel="stylesheet" class="lazyload" type="text/css">
```

I want to be able to remove this css file dynamically, from the javascript. However, at runtime, I won't have the full href available, only the `baz.css` part (That's because the file is hosted at a CDN, and the url can be dynamically generated / different each time, so it can't be hard-coded).

The css file will always have the class `lazyload`.

How can I remove this?

Comment: Just curious, why remove it?

Comment: What do you mean, "remove"?  Once the CSS has been loaded, the browser's not going to forget about it. (At least I don't think it will.)

Comment: Are there other elements with the lazyload class ?

Comment: @Pointy - That's correct, but it can be disabled though

Comment: @adeneo how can you do that? Well, I can imagine doing it if I've got control of the CSS rules themselves of course, but does messing with a `<link>` affect the rules it imported?

Comment: @Pointy - should work

Comment: @Pointy - searched and found -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182840/removing-or-replacing-a-stylesheet-a-link-with-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("link[href*='baz']").prop('disabled', true);
$("link[href*='baz']").remove();
```