# Prevent static html not to apply bootstrap css properties

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, yii

[EDIT] [SOLVED] I just replaced all my  tag with  tag with css as inline for all table   that doesn't apply any bootstrap css class properties.
Thanks all for reply.

In my yii app I having twitter bootstrap css and for some static pages I need css from style.css that I created.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <style type="text/css">
        #mystyle
        {
          /* my styles classes */
        }
     </style>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div class="mystyle">
       /* html */
     </div>
  </body
 </html>
```

here bootstrap css is also get applies.

how can i restrict this html page not to include bootstrap css??

I tried by using  tag but that not work.

Answer (score 0):

how are you adding bootstrap? are you using an extension that adds bootstrap?
if so then you can use `$this->renderPartial('path/to/full_view_with_layout');` in order to dismiss bootstrap, however I think that this is a wrong way to solve the problem. the best practise way is to include your overriding style right after the `<body>` tag or before the place you use it.
or you may have a property to disable the bootstrap in your extension.

Comment: I am not using bootstrap extension, just copy bootstrap.css, and i am using my style as inline in that .htm file as above.

Comment: Are you linking bootstrap to the page yourself or it is done by yii?

Comment: it is done by yii, i just want not to link bootstrap to this single page only

Comment: Do you use extensions in yii?

Answer (score 0):

i have another Approach, i dont know how much it will help you!

Give your own name to CSS class

If same class already exist and you are not able to change the class name,
You can add `!important` property to CSS so that bootstrap CSS will not apply.

for example

```
<style type="text/css">
        #mystyle
        {
          color:#000!important;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: This is another issue. Consider the point when you do not need any style added by bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.styleSheets[0].disabled = true;
//so in your case using jquery try

$('link[title=mystyle]')[0].disabled=true;
```

Please visit, another approach answered here

[Removing or replacing a stylesheet (a <link>) with JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182840/removing-or-replacing-a-stylesheet-a-link-with-javascript-jquery)