# adding and removing a stylesheet dynamcally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am adding a specific css file dynamically when I render a segment of html using the following.

```
loadCss("css/customCss.css");


function loadCss(href) {
  var cssLink = $("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + href + "'>");
  $("head").append(cssLink);
}
```

How can I remove a css file where the file path reference is say `css/customCssLearning`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182840/removing-or-replacing-a-stylesheet-a-link-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: What is the point of this? It doesn't take away the styles once the page is loaded....

Comment: Please update the tags on your post... it seems like you are using jQuery for your JS framework (based on your querying).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable it, removing the element does nothing. To select the element by the href value, you need to use a attribute selector.

```
$('link[href="css/customCss.css"]')[0].disabled=true;
```

and if you are going to be adding and "removing" it, you might want to check for it first and reenable it.

```
function loadCss(href) {    
    var sSheet = $('link[href="' + href + '"]');      
    if (sSheet .length) {
        sSheet[0].disabled = false;
    } else {
        var cssLink = $("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + href + "'>");
        $("head").append(cssLink);
    }
}
```

---

**Running Example:**

```js
function loadCSS(href) {
  var sSheet = $('link[href="' + href + '"]');
  if (sSheet.length) {
    sSheet[0].disabled = false;
  } else {
    var cssLink = $("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + href + "'>");
    $("head").append(cssLink);
  }
}

function removeCSS(href) {
  $('link[href="' + href + '"]')[0].disabled = true;
}



$("button.add").on("click", function() {
  loadCSS("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css");
});

$("button.remove").on("click", function() {
  removeCSS("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hello</h1>
<div class="topbar">
  <div class="icon-achievements">
    <button class="add unread-count">Add</button>
    <button class="remove unread-count">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is setting "disabled" to true on a `style` dom element supposed to un-apply the styles? because it doesn't seem to (Chrome).

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome @CodingWithSpike Try the sample above I just added.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. I had tried it on a `<style>` element, which also has a `.disabled` property but seems to do nothing. But changing `disabled` on a `<link>` element does work. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: That really solved it for me. Thank you. Also learned from your code.