# How to change CSS file or hide <link> tag

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to change the design of my site by changing the CSS file attached. I have tried with script when the link is with id "link"

```
var x = document.getElementByID ("link")
X.href = style2
```

It didn't work.

The other thing I tried was to hide the `<link>` tag which had class "linkclass"

```
<style>
link.linkclass {
  visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
```

But it didn't work either.
Can someone help.
Sorry if the code is bad formatted but I can't get how to format code in stack overflow

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets a nice article about this lengthy topic

Comment: Could it be just a typo? the code you wrote won't work because you define variable `x` and try to use variable `X`

Comment: @rafaelcpalmeida your proposed edit removes one of the key problems from the question. Never change the code itself, only whitespace.

Comment: It is not a typo. In the original document they are both x and x but I posted this from the phone and it corrected x to X

Answer (score 2):

Three things wrong with this:

1. javascript is case sensitive. That means `X` is a different variable than `x`
2. `style2` is not a valid URL. You have to use an URL to an existing .css file
3. `<link>` is not a visible element. Hiding an element that isn't visible in the first place accomplishes nothing.

This works:

```
var x = document.getElementByID("link");
x.href = "http://url/to/your/style2.css";
// ^ notice the lowercase x
```

Comment: My phone corrected the x to X but in the original document they are both x. the style2.CSS is in the same folder as the HTML file

Comment: How must it be written x.href = address or x.href = "address"

Comment: Thank you! It worked! The problem was there was no "" at the x.href = "style2"

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$("#link").disabled = true;
```

This may also work.

```
document.getElementByID("link").disabled = true;
```

There is also another Stack question that addresses this here. [Removing or Replacing a Stykesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182840/removing-or-replacing-a-stylesheet-a-link-with-javascript-jquery)

**update**

You say you are trying to change the stylesheet. You could create a function to do it like this.

```
function styleSheetSwitcher( newFile ){
    $("#link").prop("href", newFile);
}

styleSheetSwitcher("myNewCss.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna hide element (I got that impression from your examples), your javascript code should look like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("link");
x.style.display = 'none';
```

Also take care with following:

-uppercase letters getElementbyId

-you're missing semicolon (;) after first expression

-your variable "x" is uppercase in second row("X").

In most cases this should be enough to disable element with CSS, just add this class (linkclass) to element which you want to hide:

```
<style>
.linkclass {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you! The uppercase is a result I didn't copy it from the original document but wrote it again on my phone.

Comment: Glad to be of help, you can up vote answer if it helped, thanks.