# Javascript - Add and Remove CSS file with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I created a button that ADD CSS file to the page header.
How Can I REMOVE this CSS from the header with the second click on the same button?

Thanks

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myButton").click(function(){
  var ls = document.createElement('link');
  ls.rel="stylesheet";
  ls.href="myCSSfile.css";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(ls);
    });

});
</script>


<button id="myButton">Add / Remove</button>
```

Comment: Possible repeat - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182840/removing-or-replacing-a-stylesheet-a-link-with-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add something to identify the style tag, an ID seems appropriate

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myButton").on('click', function(){

        if ( $('#myStyle').length === 0 ) { // does not yet exist

            $('<link />', {
                id   : 'myStyle',
                rel  : 'stylesheet',
                href : 'myCSSfile.css'
            }).appendTo('head');

        } else { // exists, remove it

            $('#myStyle').remove();

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works! 
My final code:

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
  
  if ( $('#myStyle').length === 0 ) {
  var ls = document.createElement('link');
  ls.rel="stylesheet";
  ls.id="myStyle";
  ls.href="myCSSfile.css";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(ls);
  }
  else {
            $('#myStyle').remove();
        }
    });
});
</script>

Comment: I think this `href : 'myCSSfile.css';` line should not contain a terminator `;`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above you could also do this. This code helps you to identify the `link` tag on the basis of the `css` file you included, no need to specially identify the link tag using the `id` attribute :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myButton").click(function(){


        if($("link[href*=myCSSfile]").length){
            $("link[href*=myCSSfile]").remove();
        }
        else{
            var ls = document.createElement('link');
            ls.rel="stylesheet";
            ls.href="myCSSfile.css";
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(ls);
        }
    });

});
</script>


<button id="myButton">Add / Remove</button>
```