# set css link in not shared file asp.net core

Tags: html, asp.net

I have page which expend shared file located in  Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - ActivityMaker</title>

    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
    @Html.ApplicationInsightsJavaScript(TelemetryConfiguration)
</head>
```

How to load specific only for this page css link if all stylesheets located in shared file?

Comment: You can use partial view for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understrand your problem correctly, you can pass a variable to cshtml with ViewBag etc. and write a control to load css or not.

Also you can use client side approach with js or jquery.

Here are some links you may find useful:

1. [Removing css link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182840/removing-or-replacing-a-stylesheet-a-link-with-javascript-jquery)
2. [Loading css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript)