# How to remove css from DOM

Tags: css

I have an app which allows the user to change the theme at runtime.

Before the new CSS is loaded, this code removes the old CSS:

```
jQuery('head > link').each(function () {
            if (this.href.includes('styles/kendo.')) {
                DOM.removeNode(this);
            }
        });
```

This looks OK to me, but when it runs, something gets broken (not sure what) and later CSS does not load properly.

If I comment out this code, then the CSS loads just fine. Makes no sense to me.

Maybe there is a completely different way to remove CSS from the DOM that would be better?

Comment: Most likely you have some errors being throw, either `.href` or `.includes` being undefined. Check your console. `DOM` is also possibly undefined.

Comment: No, no error messages at all.

Comment: Are you sure? What is DOM then? Are you sure .includes is available, and all your link tags have href attributes?

Comment: Yea, DOM doesn't seem to be an inbuilt object.

Comment: Using `$(this).remove()` would be the better approach as you are already using jQuery.

Comment: Ah good point.  I need to find out what DOM is.

Comment: Have you tried `.attr()`? Try this: `if (jQuery(this).attr("href").includes("styles/kendo.")`. Are you sure you want a period in your `href`?

Comment: @DeepakKamat, Can you be more specific?

Comment: @NeilA. Yes, I will try that.

Comment: @DeepakKamat If you want to post your comment as answer, I will accept.

Comment: @GregGum I just did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine in the code till

```
jQuery('head > link').each(function () {
            if (this.href.includes('styles/kendo.')) {
```

The next line `DOM.removeNode(this);` which is supposed to remove the HTML element i.e `this` uses `DOM.removeNode` method, it is not an inbuilt object hence we do not know how does it work, probably a library in your app might have that object so you may want to check its documentation.

Better than this if our task is to remove that particular HTML link element from the DOM we can use jQuery `$.remove()` method,

```
jQuery('head > link').each(function () {
            if (this.href.includes('styles/kendo.')) {
                $( this ).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `document.styleSheets[i].disabled = true;`?

This works in plain JS (no jQuery):

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
  if (document.styleSheets[i].href.includes('styles/kendo.')) {
    document.styleSheets[i].disabled = true;
  }  
}
```

Another way in plain JS would be to use `forEach`:

```
[].forEach.call(document.styleSheets, function(element, index, array) {
  if (array[index].href.includes('localhost')) {
    document.styleSheets[index].disabled = true;
  }
});
```

(why `.forEach` starts with `[]` and uses`.call` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach))

This would be the jQuery version:

```
jQuery(document.styleSheets).each(function(i) {
  if (document.styleSheets[i].href.includes('styles/kendo.')) {
    document.styleSheets[i].disabled = true;
  }  
});
```

Here's some references on `document.styleSheet`, etc.:

- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182840/removing-or-replacing-a-stylesheet-a-link-with-javascript-jquery)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets)

Comment: Thanks very much for detailed answer.